# --prod not working when building Ionic 3 apps

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, webpack, ionic3

After a while working on my Ionic 3 project, something has changes. I googled and searched on Ionic Framework forum but with no response, the problem is frequent.

I hope someone could help.
When I run the command `ionic build --prod` (or `Ionic cordova build android --prod`), at certain stage it freezes and start consuming unlimited RAM.
Here is the details:

[image]

So I had to kill the process, otherwise it will end with memory heap.

My `package.json` is like that:

```
{
  "name": "grocery",
  "version": "1.3.0",
  "author": "hussemsoft@gmail.com",
  "homepage": "http://www.kunzo.sa/",
  "private": true,
  "config": {
    "ionic_purge_unused_fonts": false
  },
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
    "@ionic-native/call-number": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "^4.5.3",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/google-maps": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/launch-navigator": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-geocoder": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^4.5.3",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.1.10",
    "@ionic/pro": "1.0.16",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.1.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^9.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.5-next",
    "call-number": "^1.0.1",
    "cordova-android": "6.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-actionsheet": "^2.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.7",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase": "^0.1.25",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "^2.3.6",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^3.9.2",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "firebase": "^4.10.0",
    "imgcache.js": "^1.1.1",
    "ionic-angular": "^3.9.2",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": "0.0.2",
    "promise-polyfill": "^6.1.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": "^4.2.1",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.19",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.0",
    "typescript": "2.4.2",
    "uglify-es": "3.2.2"
  },
  "description": "Dukan app",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
        "GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "To locate you"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": {},
      "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-firebase": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": {},
      "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": {
        "OKHTTP_VERSION": "3.+"
      },
      "call-number": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

And ionic info gives:

```
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.10
    Cordova Platforms  : none
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v6.14.2
    npm               : 5.10.0
    OS                : Windows 10

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\HUSSEM-PC\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

I'm quite sure that it has a relation with `webpack`.

Answer (score 1):

Wait a bit, if it gives you Memory Error Try this

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1247